Como reemplazar espacios en blanco entre letras por un guion bajo?
Tengo un archivo que contiene esto:
...
no detections
3 cat 
1 person, 1 cup, 1 laptop
1 sport ball, 1 cup
...

Y quiero que todas las filas queden de esta manera:
...
no_detections
3 cat 
1 person, 1 cup, 1 laptop
1 sport_ball, 1 cup 
...

Osea que en donde hay un espacio en letra+espacio+letra se reemplace por un _, yo he intentaba con tr pero no lo pude lograr, se podra hacer con tr o con otro?, gracias.

Usa sed. Tiene documentación.

sed -r 's/([a-z]) ([a-z])/\1_\2/i' test.txt

@CandidMoe por favor, ponlo como respuesta

Muchas gracias @CandidMoe

Hola  puedes usar sed para reemplazar los espacios con guiones bajos, mira un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1_\2/g' archivo.txt

Al ejecutar esto va a reemplazar cualquier espacio entre letras con un guión bajo y tendras el resultado que quieres.
no_detections
3 cat 
1 person, 1 cup, 1 laptop
1 sport_ball, 1 cup 

Observacion: Agregue la respuesta de como solucionarlo para responder a esta pregunta, pero el usuario Candid Moe también ha dicho una forma de hacerlo en su comentario de arriba.
